# Copying a dynamically allocated 2D array

Tags: c++, arrays

I have a question as follows:

I declared two pointer-to-pointer double-type variables `**matrix1` and `**matrix2` and allocate them by `new` operator to become 2D arrays.
First I used for loop to make `matrix1` point to double-type data called `element`, then I copy `matrix1` to `matrix2`, which means `matrix2` points to `element` too. Then problem comes: I used `delete` operator to terminate `matrix1` after copying, but then the values `matrix2` point to became extremely strange. I think that was because after deleting `matrix1`, `element` terminates, so I think one of a solution is let `matrix2` point to other address with the values same with element. But I don't know how to do this(copy element to new dynamic memories and won't disappear after deleting `matrix1`) in an efficient way, can somebody help me? thank you.

```
void MatCpy(double **InMat, double **OutMat, int NumOfRow, int NumOfCol)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < NumOfRow; j++)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < NumOfCol; i++)
        {
            OutMat[j][i] = InMat[j][i];
        }
    }
}

double **Malloc2D_Dbl(int row, int col)
{
    double **data = new double*[row];

    for (int i = 0; i < row; i++)
        data[i] = new double[col];

    return data;    
}

void load(char *load_path, double **data, int height, int width) // function for loading
{
    int i = 0, j = 0;
    char buffer[30];
    file_handle = fopen (load_path, "r");   
    for (int k = 0; k < width*height; k++)  
    {
        fscanf (file_handle, "%s", &buffer);  
        j = k / width;
        i = k % width;                
        data[j][i] = atof(buffer);   
    }   
    fclose (file_handle);
}
```

Sorry I am a noob....

Comment: Can you add the code for this?

Comment: Adding code will be usefull. However, now I can imagine that the matter in the shallow copying. Ie copies only pointers to data, not the data itself.

Comment: sorry, I forgot to print my code

Comment: @user3275148 you can edit your question for code adding.

Comment: @user3275148: Can you show the code where you allocate/delete stuff?

Comment: `std::vector<std::vector<double>> x, y;` Then later on `x = y;` Done.

Comment: Thank you Matz, your code works!

Answer (score 0):

More efficient than copying the individual elements is to use `memcpy` like this:

```
void MatCpy(double **InMat, double **OutMat, int NumOfRow, int NumOfCol) {
   for(int j=0; j<NumOfRow; j++) {
        memcpy(OutMat[j], InMat[j], NumOfCol*sizeof(double));
   }
}
```